# Finding the roots of $x^4+2x^3+2x^2+x-1$

Tags: calculus

Finding the roots of $$x^4+2x^3+2x^2+x-1=0$$
I tried to find the closed-form of roots but I couldn't. Any help

Comment: [Ferrari's solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari.27s_solution)

Comment: This doesn't have real roots according to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x4%2B2x3%2B2x2%2Bx%2B1%3D0)

Comment: Also it doesn't have real roots, as $x^4+2x^3+2x^2+x+1 = \frac{1}{16} (2 x+1)^2 (4 x^2+4 x+3)+\frac{13}{16}$

Comment: I think there are real roots

Comment: You can click on the link attached to the word 'wolframalpha' in my comment.

Comment: Also, let $f$ be your polynomial, then $$f'(x)= 4x^3+6x^2+4x+1,$$ whose only real root is $-1/2$ and $f(-1/2)>0$, so the polynomial has an unique minimum at that point.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 sorry I have edited the question.

Comment: Make a change of variable y = 2x + 1

Answer (score 0):

[WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%2B2*x%5E3%2B2*x%5E2%2Bx-1%3D0) gives $x = {1\over 2} \left(-1\pm \sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}-1}\right)$ so we have an idea where to think to:
$$x^4+2x^3+2x^2+x-1 = \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^4+{1\over 2} \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-{19\over 16}$$
We denote $\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2=t$, solve $t^2+\dfrac{1}{2}t-\dfrac{19}{16}=0$, then obtain $t$ and find $x=-\dfrac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{t}$.